# Scala bounded generic type vs polymorphsim

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism

In scala, the following generic type,

```
def input[T <: SubType](inp: T) = { }
```

is replaceable with the polymorphic definition

```
def input(inp: SubType) = { }
```

When should we prefer the 1st style and 2nd style? Any scenarios?

Comment: In this particular case it doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following method:

```
def input[T <: SubType](inp: T): T = ???
```

Now the precise type of `inp` will be preserved in the return type. In the other style you would always have `Subtype` as the return type, not something more specific.

So basically you need the first style if you need access to the most precise type of `inp` known to the compiler. 
Another example:

```
def input[T <: SubType : SomeTypeclass](inp: T) = ???
```